# Adding a customixed button to view previous and next years in pikaday

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, pikaday

I am working on pikaday and customizing it.Can anyone help me how to add a button that takes us to previous year and next year (in pikaday there is a built-in prev and next button for months; I want to add an extra button to move to prev and next years along with the months).

Comment: Show us what you've tried. This is not really a place where you can ask for solutions for you task, but a place where you can ask for help for specific problems encountered when trying to solve a task.